# GeoServer GeoWebCache - disk quota subsystem disabled error

Tags: geoserver, java, geowebcache

Getting this message on my GeoServer (2.13.0):
[image]

I'm using OpenJDK Java:
`openjdk version "1.8.0_352" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_352-8u352-ga-1~18.04-b08) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)`
and a non-Tomcat installation (sorry, I've forgotten what the webserver is called)

Does anyone know what I need to do?

I'm getting "hits" when accessing the existing layers, but need to rebuild a couple of caches, and it feels like I'm unable to do this.

Comment: Try deleting the file mentioned in the error message, and check GeoServer has permission to write there if that doesn't help

Comment: Thanks Ian, that worked. Needed to restart the geoserver for everything to start working. Thank you (again :))